# AWS Lambda vs EC2: Which one to choose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to make login service which is deployed on EC22 to serverless.
But I am not sure if AWS Lambda or serverless exposed via AWS API Gateway is right fit for login use cases where after successful log in it would return `accesstoken`.

That's the only responsibility of this microservice.

And I am not sure how Lambda would behave for load test and high volume of http requests.

And, also we need to a low response time.

Could you please let me know how can Lambda scale and is this right use-case?

Comment: Can you define which response time is acceptable to you? While Lambda is extremely scalable, new instances of a Lambda function take some time (how long depends on the lambda) to start up. When this cold startup is done, subsequent requests are very fast, but you should take that into account.

Comment: I am looking for response time Less than 500ms with 2 dynamo calls in between and this is response time I expect from api gateway to lambda and return response to client for http  request

Comment: This should be doable if you rely on DynamoDB and manage to avoid services that require access to a VPC. I'd start with Lambda - turning a Lambda App into something that runs on EC2 is usually easier than the other way around.

Comment: You mean to say preferred one is ec2, if yes then why ?

Comment: No I'd prefer Lambda for a lot of reasons.

Comment: Could you please let me know reasons? So I can also get some help.

Comment: I added an answer of my own as this is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the discussion in the comments I'm now adding a complete answer to this, as this is not really suitable for a comment.

You mentioned that your current service is **already running on EC2** and you'd like to move that over to a Serverless solution. Furthermore you mention the options of "Lambda or Serverless exposed via API-Gateway". Then you add some additional information about expecting a response time of 500ms and the Lambda doing 2 DynamoDB calls.

I'll address these points in order:

**EC2 vs Serverless Solution:**

You seem to have already decided on trying the Serverless route, which works quite well in principle for a Microservice-Type architecture you're describing. I'm not going to focus too much on the merits of the EC2 solution here. Going serverless can have the following benefits (among others):

- Cost effectiveness: You pay only for the resources your code consumes while it's running and not for idle times
- Scalability: Lambda scales horizontally, fast and effortlessly - you basically don't worry about it (up to 1000 parallel "instances")
- Lower operational overhead: No need to patch operating systems - AWS takes care of that for you
- Focus on your business logic, leave the heavy lifting of managing the infrastructure to AWS

**Lambda or Serverless exposed via API-Gateway**

Serverless isn't really an AWS Service but a paradigm or architectural pattern so these options don't completely make sense - you'd use the API Gateway to trigger Lambda functions whenever an Event (read: HTTP-Request) occurs. This means you'll setup a fully-managed REST-Endpoint (API-Gateway) to call your code (Lambda) on demand.

**On Performance**

A response time of 500ms is realistic for the use case you're describing - DynamoDB advertises single-digit-millisecond latency, so two calls to it within 500ms shouldn't be a problem. Unfortunately Lambda cold-start is a thing. Lambda scales out with **parallel** requests, meaning a new Micro-VM gets provisioned if there aren't enough warm instances of your function available to serve your request. This takes time, but in your use-case this shouldn't be an issue, since you don't need access to a VPC (in that case it would take multiple seconds).

Lambda is limited in performance compared to EC2 instances, you scale the amount of performance Lambda provides by specifying the amount of RAM the function gets allocated (CPU resources are provided based on the RAM). For a simple Login-Service this shouldn't be an issue as well.

I suggest you read up on the points I mentioned in the Lambda documentation (which is quite good).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your events driven service managed use AWS Lambda, you just provide the code in the required language, and Amazon AWS does the rest. If you want to customise for your own needs and use whatever coding language you prefer Amazon EC2 offers flexibility and a whole range of EC2 Instance types to choose from, in conjunction with Elastic Beanstalk services for deploying onto Amazon EC2.

AWS Lambda is a service for running code in response to events, such as changes to data in an Amazon S3 bucket and Amazon DynamoDB tables, or as compute services to run your code in response to HTTP requests using Amazon API gateway or API calls made by using AWS SDKs. This is an ideal computing platform for applications when running within the standard runtime environment.

Lambda should be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

According to me for your use case, AWS Lambda with API Gateway is the preferred choice. Scaling in AWS Lambda is not an issue. Also using AWS Lambda you can save cost.

Please read: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon API Gateway - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html)

Comment: Ok... could you please let me know, how lambda scale up and how it actually runs a http request .
My assumption is for example of one http request is coming then it would finish it and then serve second one or is it something different?

Comment: @RahulSingh that's not the case. For each request, a new Lambda will be executed.

AWS Lambda supports 1000 concurrent executions per region (that's across all functions) by standard, with a burst increase to 3000 (main regions) & 1000 (new / smaller regions). Details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html

AWS API gateway support 1000 rps (requests per sec). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-limits

Comment: Ok...but won't it be issue if  input load is increased during peak hrs, spinning up new lambda and executing it?

Comment: @RahulSingh I don't think it will be an issue. You need to check how much memory is required by your program. If the memory requirement is small then it won't be a problem. You need to validate with some stress testing.